# Chip shorting to ground when connecting the grounds

Tags: serial, rs232, ttl

I have a pcb that converts USB to RS232, it is using a CH340G and a MAX2323. The output when not connected works as expected.

I try to connect it to a separate device that has its own power supply. When I measure the grounds of connected USB and the device, it reads 70V AC 50Hz.

When I try to connect the grounds, the chips start to heat up as a short circuit.

Any idea why this might happen?

[image: l]

Comment: Where is the USB-RS232 adapter connected to (desktop, laptop) and is it connected to grounded outlet with a grounded mains cable? What is the other device, what kind of power supply it has (grounded, ungrounded), and is it connected to anywhere else that may or might not be grounded?

Comment: Currently usb is connected to the laptop that works on the battery, the other device supply is not isolated, connected to mains.

Comment: The other device supply is ungrounded.

Comment: 70V is pretty crazy. Don't you get an electric shock when you touch that device...?

Comment: Sounds like your other device is badly designed. Devices with exposed metal (including USB connectors) *must* be either grounded or isolated. Otherwise, it seems like your device is connecting the AC mains voltage through to the USB ground. Which is stupid and dangerous.

Comment: how can it connect to ac mains if the usb connection is isolated (notebook running on battery)?

Comment: That looks pretty normal for a 2-prong ungrounded floating power supply, measured with a grounded oscilloscope. Also, when that is connected to laptop that is running on batteries, and has no other connections anywhere else, the laptop is floating. So it should not have broken. But what is the other device you are connecting to with RS232 interface? And how are you connecting to it?

Comment: It's a tachograph adapted for mains, and looks like this is the problem. When I measure the ground of the tachograph pin using the probe I get 260V AC.

Comment: What kind of mains power supply the tachograph has? And which kind of serial interface it has, TTL or RS232 ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help but it seems the MAX2323 chip was fried, after replacing it everything works as expected.